# Adobe Flash ActionScript 3 Slide linking and rollover effect

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, slideshow, mouseover, flash-cs6

I have a slideshow that is fading through and each Slide links to a different page. Have a simple text rollover effect I activate with AS3 so when the slide is rolled over the text changes color.

I can get it to work with just one slide but I can't get it to work when I add 3 more slides

```
inv_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonHandler);
inv_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, rollOver);
inv_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, rollOut);

function buttonHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.hautepets.net/pages/grooming.php")); 
}
   function rollOver(event:MouseEvent):void {
    rollText_1.gotoAndPlay("over");
}
   function rollOut(event:MouseEvent):void {
    rollText_1.gotoAndPlay("out");
}
```

Then add the code 3 more times but change instance names and also move the button for the next slide to another key frame. Not sure this is necessary but I also tried it with out doing this.

I use the exact same code I just change instance names on the new slide and in the code like so:

```
inv_btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonHandler2);
inv_btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, rollOver2);
inv_btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, rollOut2);

   function buttonHandler2(event:MouseEvent):void {
         navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.hautepets.net"));
}

   function rollOver2(event:MouseEvent):void {
        rollText_2.gotoAndPlay("over");
 }

   function rollOut2(event:MouseEvent):void {
        rollText_2.gotoAndPlay("out");
}
```

any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Need more information.  How are you adding the slides?  Are they on later frames of the same timeline? are they all there at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare these instances in the first frame, even if you don't use them
just put inv_btn2 and rollText_2 also to first frame, it will solve the problem and use visible = false/true; to show/hide them on different frames or you also can put them out of stage on first frame.